# Does my refrigerator benefit from a water filter if the water is already filtered by reverse osmosis?

Tags: refrigerator, water-filtration

The water going into my GE refrigerator, Model #:PYE22KYNFS, is already filtered by a reverse osmosis system. Do I gain anything by having a water filter on my refrigerator?

Also, if I don't need it, after it expires do I need to remove it or can I leave it in?

Thank you

Comment: Water filter *on the fridge* is probably to keep particulate crud out of the delicate ice maker and valves, where it could land on a valve face and stick the valve open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fridge filter is a simple one compared to the RO system.

Remember the instructions to flush the fridge filter with like 2 gallons when installed. That is to remove most of the particle.

It will certainly not improve the RO water quality, but it might reduce it.

Since it is actually not filtering anything after RO, just leave it in, it is not contaminated, or find and insert a blank.

Answer (score 2):

If your RO system does the job for you, you don't need the filter in the fridge. **However, do not leave the old filter in for an extended period of time!** Filter makers warn that as they age they are subject to rupture - and they will. I had it happen to me on a filter I left in for a year.
Depending on the make and model, if you leave the filter off, you may have to replace it with a cap supplied by the manufacturer.

Comment: I forgot to change mine for 5 years, it is still in there

Comment: @Ruskes - You're lucky - don't count on it!

Comment: Do you have a reference for your claim, since the filters can be stored for 10 years

Comment: @Ruskes - Yes, they can be stored unused for years. The problem is that under pressure over time they can give out. Although it is especially true of offbrand filters it also happens with OEM filters. Mine happened to be a generic filter which did have a caution on it in the fine print. I would not trust any filter to hold up long term.

Answer (score 1):

Having a water filter can't hurt...unless you leave it in for too long and it restricts or even blocks the water flow.

If you prefer not to have to deal with it, the manufacturer should have supplied a cap to be installed to use without a filter.

Comment: I would expect that feeding the built-in filter with RO filtered water should result in the built-in filter effectively lasting for ever. There shouldn't be anything in the water to cause it to ever clog up. Even if the manufacturer does supply a dummy cap for the filter you'll probably still have to reset the "replace filter" message if the fridge has one programmed to appear periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Most RO systems have filters already built into them and if they are good systems, automatically flush out debris.  Regular maintenance (about yearly) is needed to keep them in top operating condition to be sure if it does have a filter, that it's cleaned.